# Building a unified config.properties. What if there are multiple properties with the same key in a properties file in Java?

Tags: java, bash, properties

We have a situation where there are a dozen of files called `config.properties` in our build process:

- `config.properties.dev`
- `config.properties.qa`
- `config.properties.prod1`
- `config.properties.prod2`

Our current install process copies the `config.properties` for that environment to `config.properties`. (I'm not thrilled about this, but this is what I have to work with now.)

All of these files are exactly the same except for three or four properties. Unfortunately, these aren't always the same property across all of the files. What we'd like to do is setup a *master* `config.properties` like this:

#### Master `config.properties`

```
prop1 = value1
prop2 = value2
prop3 = value3
prop4 = value4
```

Then have a separate `config.properties for each environment that contains only the properties that differ from the master:

#### `config.properties.prod`:

```
prop3 = value3.1
prop4 = value4.1
```

#### `config.properties.qa`

```
prop2 = value2.1
prop3 = value3.2
```

We thought it might be possible to concatenate the two files together when we do a deployment:

```
cat config.properties.$env >> config.properties
```

And get a combined properties file this way:

#### Combined `config.properties`

```
prop1 = value1
prop2 = value2
prop3 = value3
prop4 = value4
prop2 = value2.1
prop3 = value3.2
```

Unfortunately, we don't know how Java handles such a file. Does it take the first defined property, or the last defined property, or is the behavior completely undefined?

If this won't work, what's the best way in a configuration script (which is usually a BASH script) to combine multiple properties into a single property file?

Comment: Do you use Properties or ResourceBundle during runtime? They seem to behave different, e.g. Properties extends HashMap (Hashtable) so only last key should count. ResourceBundles' source code will be a mystery to me forever...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As @home mentioned, Properties is a Map, so last one (last in the file) wins.

However, it seems to me that it would be better to resolve the proper values while consolidating the files, so that the result has exactly one instance of each property. That way, once the properties file is in use, there will be no guessing.

How you resolve these is, of course, up to you.

Comment: We have over a dozen separate properties files with about 40 to 50 values in each one. As you can imagine, if a new property is added, all files have to be updated, and that doesn't happen. You can imagine the support nightmare this causes. Our deploy script is a shell script, so it has to be something easily scriptable in shell. I'm not thrilled with the prospect of duplicate keys, but it might make maintenance easier. You add a new property, you put it in the master. If a particular environment needs a different value, you put it in that one.

Comment: What I'd really would like to do is use a database for this stuff. No special deployment is needed to _configure_ everything. DBs can be hierarchical too: _Default value_-&gt;_environment type_-&gt;_machine specific_. Config files get changed in production, but no one changes them in the source repo. Can't happen in a DB. Most importantly, it's no longer _my job_ and _my issue_ when things go wrong. Plus, IT would have to create a support ticket to get our DBs to change the value, so the whole thing is documented. Now, we know who changed the config and why.

Comment: Unfortunately, using a data base will require some restructuring of their apps from the developers, and coordinating with the DB and deployment teams to get everything setup. Everyone agrees this is the way to go, but I'm having a hard enough time just getting minimal changes incorporated. They are spending so much time putting out fires because things were done wrong, they don't have time to do it the right way.

Comment: I think that main issue to be resolved is the priority of each config file. Once you have an established pattern of "who wins", it should be pretty simple to write a script to do the consolidation.

Answer (score 0):

You might also take a look at apache commons-configuration project. It has build in facilities to combine different configuration files.

Comment: Unfortunately, I have to do this at deploy time. Although I could build the various property files for the deploy... I'll have to look into it.